# Ubuntu 22.04, Fujitsu Lifebook E5510, Keyboard not working after Update. (Kernel 6.2.0-26-generic)

Tags: kernel, keyboard, elantech

Summarize the problem:
after an minor Update (Ubuntu 22.04), internal keyboard not working for login. (Kernel 6.2.0-26-generic)

Provide details and any research:
First Check: goto Bios, Keyboard Working there, keyboard hardware probably ok. On Installing Ubuntu for first time on e5510 (ubuntu 20.04) i had problems with the touchpad which i solved, but this is actually working.

When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried:
I tried booting an older Kernel, with 5.19.0-50 everything works fine.

I tried `modprobe i2c_hid and modprobe i2c_hid_acpi` but it does not help.

I used `dmesg | grep ...` searching for hid, input, key and i2c to locate interesting parts, but everything is about touchpad and mouse, barely an entry found which hints directly to keyboard, they look similar.

```
### kernel 6.2.0-26
[    0.734497] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[    4.666515] input: Fujitsu FUJ02E3 as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/FUJ02E3:00/input/input17
### kernel 5.19.0-50
[    1.376799] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[    4.570803] input: Fujitsu FUJ02E3 as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/FUJ02E3:00/input/input17
```

any ideas are appreciated

Comment: As I also have the same issue, so I opened a bug liked to this question in Launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2033271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me with Ubuntu, although the solution is described for Fedora.

https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/fujitsu-lifebook-e5510-keyboard-not-detected/70907/18

Edit boot parameter in grub, usually after `quiet splash`:

```
i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset
```

Result:

```
quiet splash i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset
```

Worked for me.

Detailed doc for boot parameters:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

As hint for urgent workaround: using standby and wake up again solved the problem for me too, as quick solution, if no external keyboard is available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with kernel 5.15.0-82-generic (I'm on 22.04 LTS). After some research I've found out, that the laptop switched to tablet mode.
You can check if that's the case with

```
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
```

If the output is 10, then that's the case. A small inconvenient workaround is to close the lid and open it again (doesn't work with disk encryption). I've yet to find a permanent fix.

Comment: I execute the command and get 10 as result, so the Kernel switched probably to tablet mode. Close and open the lid did not help, but the fujitsu e5510 lifebook is not a convertible, no touchscreen or screen rotate. Thanks anyway, tablet mode is a new hint i can follow.